# Pass arguments to Python argparse within Docker container

Tags: python, docker, command-line-arguments

I am embarking on my first attempt at utilizing a docker container.  I have a python script that calls a couple API's and parses a file.  The script took parameters for the URL of the server for the API, the API key, and the file path for the file to parse.  I used argparse to handle these in the script.

How do I get get these passed into Docker?  I do not want to hard code anything as I am looking to hand this script off to an engineer who needs to run this periodically and take action based on the results.

Thanks for your help.  I have been searching but it seems like hard coding things into the dockerfile is the suggestion - I want the user to be able to put these in at run time.  Or perhaps I have found the answer and am just not understanding it....

I apologize if my lingo is not right - this is my first attempt at utilizing Docker.

Answer (score 77):

The way you do it depends on how your using docker. If you want to run your script in an already running container, you can use exec:

```
docker exec <yourContainerName> python <yourScript> <args>
```

Alternatively, if you have a docker image where your script is the ENTRYPOINT, any arguments you pass to the docker run command will be added to the entrypoint.

So, if your docker file looks like this:

```
FROM yourbase
....
ENTRYPOINT <yourScript>
```

Then you can just run the script by running the container itself:

```
docker run --rm <yourImageName> <args>
```

Based on your comment below, it looks like you want this option. You should change your dockerfile to specify

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python","./script.py"]
```

(instead of using CMD)
and then you can run via:

```
docker run --rm <yourImageName>  -a API_KEY - f FILENAME -o ORG_ID
```

Comment: So my python script is the reason for the container.  I just have:   "CMD ["python","./script.py"]" in the Dockerfile but I want to pass "-a API_KEY -f FILENAME -o ORG_ID"

Comment: It might be important to mention that you need to use the exec form `ENTRYPOINT ["python","./script.py"]` instead of the shell form `ENTRYPOINT python ./script.py` to be able to propagate the parameter(s) into python.

Comment: @naeschdy yes, that's what was bothering me. you're right

Comment: i really like the entrypoint  you can build then is really like using your program locally just adding the "docker run <imageName>" instead "python <app_name>.py" in the cli

Answer (score 37):

So let's assume your command is below

```
python app.py "URL" "APIKEY" "filepath"
```

So you will put your Dockerfile in below fashion

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /app
COPY app.py .
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

Then the person running the docker container would do it like below

```
docker run -v /home/tarun/project/filetoparse.yaml:/config.yaml <yourimagename> "URL" "APIKEY" /config.yaml
```

If you want to give more flexibility you an can even use environment variables

```
docker run -v /home/tarun/project/filetoparse.yaml:/config.yaml -e APIKEY="XYZ" <dockerimage> "URL" /config.yaml
```

And then in your script you can read it using `os.environ['APIKEY']`

Comment: I got an error saying unrecogized arguments. Is it because of the difference of docker versions?

Answer (score 22):

This answer is kind of late but for any future readers, i would like to make it more towards the question asked i.e. with respect to argparse.

The basic idea like @Chris pointed out is it. One way to achieve the solution is to pass arguments to the `image` in docker run command itself. These arguments would then be passed to your `ENTRYPOINT`, therefore passing to the python script.

The files would look something like this typically..

### file.py

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('pos', type=str, help='Example Positional Argument') # will be accesible under args.POS
parser.add_argument('--opt', type=str , help='Example Optional Argument') # will be accesible with args.OPT

args = parser.parse_args()

# do something with pos and OPT
```

Without docker, You would run this file (assuming it is in the pwd) as `python file.py --opt opt_val pos_val`

### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:<your_tag>
COPY ./file.py ./ # Assuming your Dockerfile and file.py are in the same directory

# some custom build steps

ENTRYPOINT ["python","./file.py"]
```

### Docker build and run commands

You build with this : `docker build --tag  example:0.0.1 <dir>`

The below shows multiline(for better readability) run commands,

#### Docker run

```
docker run --rm \
   --name example.container \
   example:0.0.1 \
   --opt=opt_val \
   POS=pos_value
```

#### Docker run (powershell)

```
docker run --rm `
   --name example.container `
   example:0.0.1 `
   --opt=opt_val `
   POS=pos_value
```

So here are some points to remember:

- Argparse has support for adding positional and optional arguments and should be passed accordingly to the `image` in the `docker run` command.
- The solution pointed out above works but is not as flexible as id generally like it to be. Better to use Environment variables and access inside the script with `os.environ()`.
- With this solution you dont "hard-code" anything to the Dockerfile

Answer (score 16):

Inside `Dockerfile`, i use the [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) command like this:

```
FROM python:3
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r req.pip
CMD ["python","start.py","(api-url) ","(api-key)","(file-path)"]
```

**Note** Per each args/params, separate with coma

If you are using flags, you will need to split

```
CMD ["python","start.py","-u","(api-url) ","-k","(api-key)","-f","(file-path)"]
```

Comment: I think the question was looking for a solution to flexibly pass the arguments when running docker, instead of hard-coding them in the Dockerfile.

Comment: This is helpful when using the REST endpoint of docker engine to create containers from an image dynamically, passing docker.conf as JSON payload.